# Focus On Password Field If Username Has Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My request is simple, I have a login form. We have a "save username" option on the login form. When the page loads, if the username input field has value (they have saved their username) I want to Autofocus on the password input instead of the username input.

Below is the jQuery I currently have which is not working:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            if($('#username').val() != ''){
                $('#p').focus();
            }
    });
```

Currently nothing happens, there are no console errors and the #username input stays focused or highlighted.

Any ideas on how to focus on an input field so the user can start typing there automatically?

Comment: Are you doing it on document ready? If not, wrap it and watch the magic.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see this in action?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect to happen, and what occurs instead?

Comment: Yes I am. I have updated code accordingly. I also did some alerts and the IF is evaluating true. So it is running the $('#p').focus();

Comment: I believe it's a simple timing issue. `focus` is quite capricious sometimes. Try giving a bit more time to the browser `setTimeout(function () {/*set focus*/}, 50);`

Comment: Is the element visible? Change it to window load.

Comment: Thanks all. It was a simple as wrapping the script in a setTimeout function. Thanks Plalx for solving this! All fixed now.

Comment: Just for the record Window.load was a better solution. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it out of `$(document).ready()`, use:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    if($('#username').val() != ''){
        $('#p').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: This turns out to be the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Thanks plalx for pointing out the timing issue.

I needed to wrap the script in a "set timeout" function. Below is the final working script.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      if($('#username').val() != ''){
         setTimeout(function () {
            $('#p').focus();
          }, 50);
      }
  });
```

Comment: setTimeout is a bad idea... Call it on window load

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specity if user has saved the username or not.
2. Then you have to see what usernamehas been saved.
3. Then focus on the password field.

Here is your code

```
var saveduser="piyush"; //get username from saved fields
    $(window).ready(function(){
        if(saveduser!="")
        {
            $("#user").val(saveduser);
            $("#pass").focus();
        }
    });
```

Here is the fiddle that I have created

http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/86XxN/1/

You can set variable `saveduser` to username using javascript cookies or php.

Comment: This is a good solution thanks. It's more than I need at this point but does it's job well.